# Can I use LC 16340 batteries to power a Raspberry PI 3 B

Tags: batteries, raspberry-pi, lithium-ion, discharge

A long time ago I accidentally bought a bunch of LC 16340 lithium ion batteries that have been recently wasting away in my office. I am not big into EE but what I think I know is I need a discharge circuit for these batteries to ensure the 5.1v 2.5 amp needed by the pi. Problem is I can't find a board that supports 16340.

So question is, how would I use 16340s (in whatever configuration) to power a Raspberry Pi B? Or is that even possible?

Comment: The raspberry pi uses 5V

Comment: You are right I got volts and amps mixed up I edited the question

Comment: Also LC 16340 is just the shape of the battery right? You won't need to find something specifically designed for that shape, as long as it works with lithium-ion batteries in general.

Comment: I think so again I am not that experienced. So it sounds like look for something that can be 3d printed and use a discharge board like this? https://www.ebay.com/i/112312193839?chn=ps&dispItem=1 (only matching the specs)

Comment: Sure, that circuit looks like it should work. Note it's only designed for one cell (battery). If you have a 1000mAh cell it'll probably last somewhere between every 30 minutes and 2 hours depending on how much power your Pi is using. If you want to use multiple cells I believe it's safest to put them in series rather than parallel, and you'll want to find a circuit designed for that.

Comment: I was looking and in order to get over 2500mAh (which I think is 2.5 amps) and over 5v I would need to run a 2S2P right? So would my discharge board need to be larger as well? (specs 3.7v 2400 mAh)

Comment: First you need to learn the difference between mA and mAh.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a boost coverter as pictured on your e-bay link, any Li-Ion cell will be able to power your Pi3 device. The difference will be only how long the particular battery will last.

If you use a normal 18650 size of cell, with typical capacity of 2500 mAh, (about 3.6*2.5= 9 watt-hours of stored energy), your Pi-3 will last about 10 hrs (typical web-browsing consumption of Pi3 is about 200 mA).

If you use a much smaller 16430 (4/5 AA size battery), it has typical capacity of 400-600 mAh, or about 20% of 18650 cell, so the Pi3 will last proportionally less time, maybe 2 hours.

> NOTE: you can't possibly get 2500 **mAh** out of 500 mAh battery. But you
>   might be able to get 2.5 **A** of current from it, or even much more. But
>   for a short period of time only.

Out of curiosity, you can try a tiny 130-mAh Li-Ion battery used for small quadcopters. The circuit booster still should work, but the battery will last probably less than 30 minutes.

Correction: 16430 is of CR123 size, it has about 1/2 volume of 18650 cell, and therefore it can have maximum 1200 mAh with contemporary technology (year 2017), typically less than that.

Comment: This is somewhat overlooking the discharge current rating.  LC16340's seem like they generally have a fairly low "C" rating, and may simply not be able to provide sufficient current to acehive 2+ amps at 5v after the boost ratio is taken into account.  Quadcopter type batteries even when tiny tend to claim 20, 30, even 40 "C" and so while smaller might do it - but perhaps only for a few minutes, not a half hour.

Comment: Raspberry Pi3 doesn't need 2A at 5V. Even when fully loaded (LAN, WiFi, BT, CPU 100%, GPU playback), it takes about 4W (0.8A), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9pZkS7mnq8 We are not talking about thermal viruses here, don't we? With Raspberian running idle with WiFi on, it needs only 200 mA from 5 V supply. If USB is connected, 50 mA more

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes, discharge rating should be taken into account. But at the level of OP question, this detail will be lost in noise. Actually, if a copter battery is rated for 130 mAh and high-discharge operation of 10C or more, it means that it will deliver 1.3 A with no problem for 6 minutes. For Pi3 you would need just about 300 mA from it, so it will last 25 minutes for sure.